# Why fetch function is being called twice on component load in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have hook which fetched the first 10 posts from jsonplaceholder site.
i can see in network tab that fetch req is being called twice.
i have used useEffect, useCallback & useState hook from react

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const useAppHook = ({ ref }) => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const [start, setStart] = useState(0)

  const fetchPosts = useCallback(async () => {
    const postFetchUrl = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=${start}&_limit=10`
    const response = await fetch(postFetchUrl)
    const postExtracted = await response.json()
    if (postExtracted.length) {
      setPosts((current) => [...current, ...postExtracted])
    }
  }, [start])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts()
  }, [fetchPosts])

  const handlePagination = () => {
    setStart((current) => current + 10)
  }

  return {
    posts,
    handlePagination,
  }
}

export default useAppHook
```

fetch req should happen once

Comment: I suppose, [this](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development) will shed some light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have `<StrictMode>` tag as a parent of component that uses `useAppHook`. It enables React's **Strict Mode** which helps identify common React pitfalls by mounting/unmounting/remounting components. This happens in development build only and not in production build.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these.

1. Use useRef to keep track of fetching data with start, if you fetched data with start, you don't call it again.
2. Disable React Strict Mode

[https://upmostly.com/tutorials/why-is-my-useeffect-hook-running-twice-in-react#:~:text=Simply%20remove%20the%20%3CReact.,page%2Dby%2Dpage%20basis](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/why-is-my-useeffect-hook-running-twice-in-react#:%7E:text=Simply%20remove%20the%20%3CReact.,page%2Dby%2Dpage%20basis).

Answer (score 0):

Imo this is not a good use of hooks. You generally want to avoid using hooks for user-driven events like this. This is presumably triggered by a user clicking the next page. So you should refactor your code to respond directly to that event.

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const useAppHook = ({ ref }) => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const [start, setStart] = useState(0)
  
  useEffect(() => {
   handlePagination()
  }, [])

  const fetchPosts = (start) => {
    const postFetchUrl = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=${start}&_limit=10`
    const response = await fetch(postFetchUrl)
    const postExtracted = await response.json()
    if (postExtracted.length) {
      setPosts((current) => [...current, ...postExtracted])
    }
  }

  const handlePagination = async() => {
    const newStart = current + 10;
    setStart(newStart)
    await fetchPosts(newStart)
  }

  return {
    posts,
    handlePagination,
  }
}

export default useAppHook
```

When you start introducing dependencies from user-events in useEffect/useCallback, you inevitably end up with more conditional logic to maintain in hooks which in this case can be easily avoided.

Comment: Hi Danny, your above code did not load anything in initially, i want to load first 10 posts and then want to use pagination

Comment: See my update, if you want to paginate 1x initially, in that case you can call `handlePagination` in a `useEffect` with no dependencies (so it will fire on mount) to load the initial data